# SpringBoot spring-boot-starter-web-services and spring-boot-starter-webflux breaks DSL Routes

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, tomcat, reactive-programming, netty

I'm starting a project using spring boot and webflux (Reactive) with Kotlin. I look into this blog https://kotlinexpertise.com/spring-webflux-with-kotlin-reactive-web/ and the sample works just fine. The application runs on Netty. The dependencies are :

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
}
```

Now i need to use `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services` because i have a repository that relies on a SOAP Webservice. Just by adding this dependency the application runs now on a Tomcat, and the routing configuration does not work anymore (i get a 404 when requesting http://localhost:8080/reactive). Am very new to spring but from what i understand from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-webflux-concurrency#reactive_programming_with_spring_webflux this should still work. The dependencies are

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
}
```

What am i missing ?

Comment: Spring WS requires a Servlet container, Netty isn't a servlet container so that won't work. Also when using WebFlux with tomcat it isn't fully reactive but rather the Async Servlet API will be adapted for this. You would still need the traditional way of mapping and use the non reactive Router Function or `@Controller` but still can use `Mono` or `Flux` as a return type.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @M.Deinum is there a supported way to make SOAP calls in a fully reactive stack instead of relaying on `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-service` (Am currently using `WebServiceGatewaySupport`)

Comment: Nope. You would need to create that yourself.